# Apache Camel getUri of ToDefinition in version >= 2.16.0

Tags: apache-camel

i have jsut upgraded my camel version and some functionality that was working before version 2.16.0 is now broken, I used to be able to get the URI for a toDefinition that replaced a placeholder, having just upgraded, this now doesnt replace the placeholder.

Code example is as follows:

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="config.properties" />

<route>
        <from uri="direct:input" />
        <to uri="mq:queue:{{MY_PLACEHOLDER}}" />
</route>
```

**config.properties**

```
MY_PLACEHOLDER=FOO
```

**Camel version 2.15.5**

```
toDefinition.getUri() // equals mq:queue:FOO
```

**Camel version 2.16.0**

```
toDefinition.getUri() // equals mq:queue:{{MY_PLACEHOLDER}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Also get your Camel versions correct, its not 15.5 or 16.0, its 2.16.0, 2.15.5 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is how its intended to be. The model is the model as it was designed (in this case with placeholder value).

The resolved uri is when Camel startup and runs the routes. So you can take that uri, and ask Camel to resolve, there is an API on CamelContext for that `resolvePropertyPlaceholders`

http://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.18.2/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#resolvePropertyPlaceholders-java.lang.String-